# Lenovo IS6XM can't detect GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, lenovo

My father gave me his old ThinkCentre from his office that has a Lenovo IS6XM Motherboard installed in it so I figured I could make use of it. I decided to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on it, as the only OS, but no matter how hard I try the motherboard refuses to detect the HDD as a bootable drive, simply calling it by the HDD's name. When I force it to try and boot off of it, I just get a message saying I don't have an operating system.

I plugged the same HDD into my main desktop and it could boot off of it perfectly.

Comment: With drive in system, boot Ubuntu live installer & run this: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I apologize for the late response but I got the boot repair report.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SW5qFnwKmr/

Comment: Some early UEFI implementations used description as part of UEFI boot. That was not allowed per UEFI. And only valid description was "Windows Boot Manager".  Your Windows entry is invalid & can be replaced with one that boots grub/shim. Use this to remove Windows entry: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi & option IV here to create new Windows entry that boots Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win Your ESP is sda1, so defaults work ok. Otherwise added parameters required. see `man efibootmgr`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.